# Why do plants produce and store both amylose and amylopectin?

Tags: biochemistry, plant-physiology, nutrition

Since both forms of starch has its primary purpose of storing glucose and hence releasing energy, why are there 2 variations of this sugar? Is it possible for an organism to contain/depend only on 1 but not the other?